# client send json and retrieve it in server

Tags: web-services, yii, unity-game-engine

Now I'm bulding game by UNITY3D. 
 I want to send json file to server to store it in database
 I build server by php with Yii Framework, i have problem with send data in client [UNITY3D] and retrieve it in server [Yii]. 
 Please help me.
UNITY3D code: I want to send 'name' -> to server

```
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/TPP/index.php/site/saveName";
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField( "player", "Henry" );
    var download = new WWW( url, form );
    print(download);
    yield download;

    if(download.error) {
        print( "Error downloading: " + download.error );
        return;
    } else {
        // show the highscores
        Debug.Log(download.text);
    }
```

In Yii, i tried to get data in request
        public function actionSaveName() {

```
    if(isset($_POST['name']) {
        echo $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        echo "nothing";
    }


}
```

Is that right?

Comment: what problem? what have you tried so far? have you tried anything?

Comment: I edited my question with detail code, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unity part is fine, but in yii you'll have to check for `$_POST['player']` instead of `$_POST['name']` because according to the [AddField() documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html), the first parameter is the name of the generated form element.

If you want to have it as `name` then you'll have to change AddField as : `form.AddField("name", "Henry");`

Comment: btw, i don't work on unity so i don't know how exactly it works, but according to the documentation that's what i think should work, try it and see. do let me know how it works.